# Retrieving SSH keys

Tags: windows, git, ssh, windows-8

On my Windows 8.1 dev machine I have replaced my broken HDD with a new one and installed Git. I now want to continue to commit changes to a project (which I've copied, with `git` folder, to my new HDD from a backup) using the same credentials I used before. But my `SSH` keys are now irretrievably lost on the old HDD. Is there a way to continue to contribute to the project as "me"?

Comment: Your "git identity" is usually tied to your email address, not to ssh keys. What are you using the keys for?

Comment: Thanks - I am a little bit unsure about the whole thing to be honest. I assumed that to push to Bitbucket (in this case) some kind of ssh keys were required, I'm sure I did that last time...

Comment: Yes, remote repositories might use SSH for access. You could simply create a new SSH key pair and add the new public key to your Bitbucket account. At least that's how one would do it with GitHub.

Comment: You were right, thank you very much! Feel free to add this as an answer & I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SSH to authenticate against a remote repository, then you don't necessarily need your old key. You can generate a new key pair and add the public key to your remote repository. How that works in detail depends on what service you are using.

Your "git identity" is tied to your name and email address used in commits, not to your method of authentication.